# Evaluating $\big(\cot \frac{\pi}{18}-3\cot \frac{\pi}{6}\big)\cdot \big(\csc \frac{\pi}{9}+2\cot \frac{\pi}{9}\big)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Finding value of $\displaystyle \bigg(\cot \frac{\pi}{18}-3\cot \frac{\pi}{6}\bigg)\cdot \bigg(\csc \frac{\pi}{9}+2\cot \frac{\pi}{9}\bigg)$

Try: $$\cot \frac{\pi}{18}\csc \frac{\pi}{9}-3\sqrt{3}\csc \frac{\pi}{9}+2\cot \frac{\pi}{18}\cot\frac{\pi}{9}-6\sqrt{3}\cot \frac{\pi}{9}$$

could some help me how can i simplify it,thanks

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the given.

Comment: What's the source of the nice problem?

Comment: Actually someone asked me. May be from jee mains mock papers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\cot x-3\cot3x=\dfrac{\cos x\sin3x-3(\cos3x\sin x)}{\sin x\sin3x}$$

Again,

\begin{align}
2\cos x\sin3x-3(2\cos3x\sin x)
&=\sin4x+\sin2x-3(\sin4x-\sin2x)\\[4px]
&=4\sin2x-2\sin4x \\[4px]
&=4\sin2x(1-\cos2x)\\[4px]
&=4\sin2x(2\sin^2x)
\end{align}

Finally,
\begin{align}
\csc2x+2\cot2x
&=\dfrac{1+2\cos2x}{\sin2x}\\[4px]
&=\dfrac{1+2(1-2\sin^2x)}{\sin2x}\\[4px]
&=\dfrac{\sin3x}{\sin x\sin2x}
\end{align}
for $\sin x\ne0$ using $\sin3x$ formula.

Can you identify $x$ here?